# Magento 2.1.3 Plugin problem

Tags: magento2, plugin

I m trying to understand how plugins works with M2.

I have created a few plugins for some functions.
Such as: 
addProduct
setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn
both taken from examples.
These are working.

The one doesn't work is from ShippingInformationManagement.
The function I m trying to catch is saveAddressInformation.

More or less the code is this:
etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="Vendor_WelcomePlugin::before_shipping" type="Vendor\WelcomePlugin\Plugin\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and the class:

```
namespace Vendor\WelcomePlugin\Plugin;

use \Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    public function afterSaveAddressInformation(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ){

        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $addressInformation->getBillingAddress();
        if($billingAddress->getCountryId() != 'US' || $address->getCountryId() != 'US'){
            throw new StateException(__('You can\'t order this book.'));
        }

        return array($cartId, $addressInformation);
    }

}
```

On the same topic I wasn't able to understand why I couldn't catch setCustomerAsLoggedIn function but I could make it work for setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn. Both are inside the Customer/Model/Session.php class

I have read the limitations of plugins but maybe I don't understand something.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

**Vendor/WelcomePlugin/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
    <plugin name="Vendor_WelcomePlugin::before_shipping" type="Vendor\WelcomePlugin\Plugin\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**Vendor/WelcomePlugin/Plugin/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php**

```
namespace Vendor\WelcomePlugin\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{
    public function aroundSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {

        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $addressInformation->getBillingAddress();
        if($billingAddress->getCountryId() != 'US' || $address->getCountryId() != 'US'){
            throw new StateException(__('You can\'t order this book.'));
        }

        return $proceed($cartId, $addressInformation);
    }
}
```

Comment: No still doesn't work. Does it matter at which step is that function called?

Comment: Check file location and Clear cache. It should work. It's working fine here.

Comment: Right.Yes it is working even with after or before. Problem was the di.xml file that I put it inside the frontend folder.It needs to go inside etc. Thanks